# What are the steps to enable Apple monitor on Centos 7

Tags: multiple-monitors, centos, mini-displayport

I have Centos7 installed on a Dell XPS L502X which has a thunderbolt compatible? (Mini DisplayPort) port.  I've plugged in my Apple Mac monitor but predictably enough Centos detects it as an unknown monitor and can't push any display to it.

I assume I'm going to have to do some low level config here.

**Update after comment:**  The resolution CentoOS claims it detects is 1024x768 - but I suspect that's some sort of default.  Enabling the extra monitor at that resolution didn't work. The monitor is capable of a resolution 2650x1440

Where's a good place to start?

Comment: whats the resolution of it?there were some known bugs related to it,https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56834